# Jekyll theme shows without syntax highlighting

Tags: css, jekyll

This question has been asked before, but *none of the answers* were helpful to my case. (Please see below)

I am running Jekyll 2.5.3, with the [Ion Theme](https://github.com/CloudCannon/Ion-Jekyll-Theme), and so far I was playing with it, successfully including LaTeX in posts. Now I was adding **source code** snippets, but the syntax highlighting isn't working.

I've tried all the things in the list below, and I was missing some CSS entries, but I don't know where or how I could include the styles. Note that **classes are correctly added** to the generated HTML, but I only get a monospaced font:

```
<div class="highlighter-rouge">
    <pre class="highlight">
        <code>
            <span class="cp">&lt;?php</span>
            <span class="k">echo</span>
            <span class="s1">'Hello world!'</span>
            <span class="p">;</span>
            <span class="cp">?&gt;</span>
        </code>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Manually I've modified the CSS file (`css/style.css`) adding some styles from the default Jekyll theme:

```
/* SYNTAX HIGHLIGHT */
pre.highlight {
    background: #fff;
}
    .c     { color: #998; font-style: italic } // Comment
    .err   { color: #a61717; background-color: #e3d2d2 } // Error
    .k     { color: #000; font-weight: bold } // Keyword
    .o     { font-weight: bold } // Operator
    /* ... */
```

Note that the `pre.highlight` style **works**, if I change the background (or anything else) it works. I also made this CSS to load last, just to be sure.

I've tried may combinations (`span.c`, `code span.c`, ...), but I have almost zero experience with CSS, the only thing I had successfully modified is the `pre.highlight`, which originally was only `.highlight`.

Can anyone help me with this "*little*" issue? It's been driving me mad for some days...

Thanks!

- [Jekyll Syntax Highlighting Not Working - Classes Are Not Being Added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404142/jekyll-syntax-highlighting-not-working-classes-are-not-being-added)
- [Syntax highlighting markdown code blocks in Jekyll (without using liquid tags)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648390/syntax-highlighting-markdown-code-blocks-in-jekyll-without-using-liquid-tags)
- [Pygments syntax highlighting in Jekyll without starting a <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12441501/pygments-syntax-highlighting-in-jekyll-without-starting-a-div)
- [Jekyll incorrect syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598836/jekyll-incorrect-syntax-highlighting)

Comment: Rouge is compatible Pygments stylesheets, and typically you choose [one of the existing "styles"](https://github.com/richleland/pygments-css) and include that whole CSS file on your site rather than mixing the individual CSS bits in your own. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes @briantist, unfortunately I've tried moving to `rouge`, and `pygments`. None worked.

Comment: I was asking if you added the proper stylesheet to your site. Whether you're using rouge or pygments, you still need to add a stylesheet and make sure it's being loaded, otherwise you won't get any colors. I looked at the Ion theme's CSS; I don't think it's doing this for you.

Comment: I think so, I've added the above CSS lines to the main file. As I said, the pre highlight part actually works, but the other lines don't.

Comment: Before you go manually adding lines of CSS, try using one of the standard CSS files I linked to and see if it works. If you want to further customize from there, you can edit the CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I've noted that styles were loaded in `head` with `noscript`, I've moved *outside* noscript, and it works. No idea why it was that way, though...